# "Normalise" or "normalize" (British English)?

Tags: british-english, word-usage, ise-ize

Is ***normalise*** perhaps obsolete in British English, and ***normalize*** preferred instead?

I **have** done some Googling, it seems British English dictionaries prefer ***normalize***, but I haven't found any satisfactory answers from native speakers. I would like to hear about usage and "how it sounds" (the formality), maybe if there are any reasons to use both forms in different situations.

(The question arose when reading something about *vector normalization*.)

Comment: Remember too that OUP uses the *z*-forms for things like *normalize* (but not for things like *catalyse*).

Comment: Also see [“s” vs. “z” in BE vs. AE](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80599) and the four questions linked to it

Comment: In everyday writing, people normally use **normalise**.

Comment: Also see [The use of -ize and -ise in the UK?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84102), should-be-del'ed [What is more widely used in UK English: -ise or -ize?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84103), [Are the endings "-zation" and "-sation" interchangeable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/707), [How to know when the z can't be used instead of s in an ending?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106040), [What is the difference between summarizes and summarises?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34037), & [Virtualisation vs Virtualization](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11788)

Comment: See also [Is “denormalized” a word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1184)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience (as a BrE speaker who works in IT, where I suppose the word does sometimes crop up), "normalise" definitely isn't obsolete.  I use "normalise", and similarly I stick to "realise", "formalise" and so on.  Many Brits use "ise" endings and many use "ize", not just for "normalis/ze" but for all the rest.  Each person is likely to be consistent in their own usage. I can't imagine anyone using an "ise" ending for most such words but then switching to "ize" for "normalize" - that just seems inconsistent for no good reason.

Answer (score 8):

I am not a native speaker, but I am in IT and spell it with a Z in code comments

[Google NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=normalize%2Cnormalise&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) produces these graphs

British
[image: GB]
American
[image: US]

Comment: Ha! This proves that the use of 'normalise' has been at an all-time high since 2000 (amongst other things).

Comment: @Edwin: It proves you need to be careful with normalised graphs when you have less data after 2000, perhaps why Google by default sets the end date as 2000.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a native Englishman working in IT, and most people I know (including myself) use normalise in written communication. I also use normalise() throughout vector libraries that I've written in the past. This is not uncommon in SDK's developed by UK companies.

Very few people use normalize() in the UK, although it is now more common in people for whom English is a second language (Americanisation of teaching materials perhaps?). Similarly centre vs. center, colour vs color, the pronunciation zed instead of zee for "z" etc.